# An outbuilding that is unite with the main building

Tags: word-request

I was trying to find a word for a building that was built as an outbuilding but was afterward(s) united with the main building.

> **Outbuilding** says: *a building, such as a shed, barn, or garage, on the
>   same property but separate from a more important one, such as a house.*

In my case it isn't separate.

Comment: "Building extension" comes to mind, or "[building annex](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/annex)"

Comment: You mean that is has extended? But you see this building was firstly built separate (as an outbuilding).

Comment: Then annex might be better, but I don't think there's a word for "formerly outbuilding, now annex/extension".

Comment: @MorganFR Okay, that sounds like the right word. Make it an answer or I will!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of words that would fit a building or construct that could be either connected or not.

> Building [extension](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/extension) - this is by definition connected to the main building.
>
> Building [annex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/annex) (see definition noun 1) - this can be connected to the main building but not necessarily (an attic would be connected, an outhouse or a barn probably wouldn't).
>
> Building auxiliary would also work.

To my knowledge there is no word that means that it was formerly non connected, but became connected later on, so I would say that "*annex*" does cover this particular case, without being the exact definition. An annex could also be a new building that was originally built by someone else but later on acquired.

Comment: I disagree. "Annex" as dictionaries tell has one meaning: *a building that is joined to a main building.* In this case I don't think it matters where it was built as an outbuilding after the main building was built or before that.

Comment: @SovereignSun Consider this definition from the link I provided for Annex - a building **added on to** a larger one or an auxiliary building **situated near** a main one. This one does say it can be either attached or near, so it covers your example. I am not sure why you said you disagreed since we both seem to agree that it works for your example.

Comment: Annex - a subsidiary building or an addition to a building.

Comment: How does that not support my answer? The addition can be made after it's construction, or maybe even a new acquisition of the annexed part like an auxiliary building, or directly built as an addition like an extension. I still think we're saying the same thing.

Comment: Probably - maybe! Anyway you've given all I've ask for!

Answer (score 0):

**Annex** - a building joined to or associated with a main building, providing additional space or accommodation.

Comment: @MorganFR Consider https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/annex this definitions: *something annexed as an expansion or supplement as a subsidiary or supplementary building or structure or a building that is attached to or near a larger building and usually used as part of it.* I consider it to be a **"wing"**

Comment: That's another definition of the word, and it looks like it could still work in your example. It could either become a wing or just an attic or something like that.